# Solve the congruence system: $p \equiv 11\pmod{24}$ and $ p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> I want to find the solutions of the congruences system:
> $p \equiv 11\pmod{24}$ and  $ p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

I probably have some mistake in my solution, can you tell me where I'm wrong?

$ 4 $ and $24$ are non co-primes so I can't use Chinese theorem.
So I used this: [image]

and becuase $24=2^3 * 3 $ I found the solution for the equivalent system: $p \equiv 2\pmod3$ and  $ p\equiv 3\pmod 4 $ and now I used the Chinese theorem and found that $ p\equiv 11\pmod{12} $.

But when trying to check my answer, I noticed that for exmaple  $ 23\equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ but it's not true that  $ 23\equiv 11\pmod{24}$ which is the original congruence, so what did I do wrong? And could anyone explain to me the method to solve congruences like this where the modulos are not coprime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\equiv11\pmod{24}$ then $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$, because if $p=11+24k$ for some $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ then 
$$p=3+4(2+6k),$$
with $2+6k\in\Bbb{Z}$. So you only need to solve $p\equiv11\pmod{24}$.

The equivalent system, using the Chinese Remainder theorem, should be
$$p\equiv2\pmod{3}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad p\equiv3\pmod{8},$$
the latter congruence should be modulo $8$. Breaking down congruences this way is a good approach to solving systems of modular equations, also when the moduli are not coprime.

Comment: thank you, but what is wrong with the way that I broke down the congruences? I used the theorem that I wrote in the post

Comment: Because $24=2^3\times3$, the Chinese remainder theorem allows you to check the congruence for the *maximal* prime powers dividing $24$, which are $2^3$ and $3^1$, i.e. $8$ and $3$. Not $4$ and $3$.

Comment: How do I decide to break down? I mean why couldn't it be p congruent to 2 mod 8 and p congruent to 3 mod 3?

Comment: Because $p\equiv11\pmod{24}$ implies that $p\equiv11\pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv11\pmod{8}$, by an argument similar to the one in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$p\equiv11\pmod{24}\implies p\equiv11\pmod4\equiv3$$

So, it is sufficient to have $$p\equiv11\pmod{24}$$